# How to get the data in the text File by clicking on a link using PHP

Tags: php, html

Here is my code that gets the value of the text file which is home.txt

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_content() {
    document.getElementByID('hidden_content').style.display = 'active';
}
</script>
    <title>CMS</title>
</head>
<?php
$myFile = "home.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fclose($fh);
echo '<div id="hidden_content" style="display:none">'.$theData.'</div>';
?>
<a href="cms.php" onclick="show_content()">Show it!</a>
```

This code is not getting my file text when I click the "show" link. I am not getting any error. Please help me

Comment: What error are you getting? Or what is happening?

Comment: When i click on the show it link it does not show home.text file value

Comment: Can you update my code to remove bugs if there are.

Comment: [Edit] the question and clarify it based on comments. Comments can be deleted and are not part of the Q&A. Show your research along with any errors or messages. No one is going to fix your code for you, so you are expected to debug it yourself.

Comment: @cmac can you give me code that will display the content of the text file when i click on the link

Comment: @jdv i have posted code that not show the content of the home.txt , no any error is showing

Comment: @FameFamous see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: @FameFamous did it work or are you still having trouble?

Comment: When you view the source for the page what do you see? Is the data making it to the source of the page and just not being displayed, or is the php failing to get the file contents into the source of the page?

Comment: First, `display: active` is not valid CSS, please try to substitute `active` with `block` and report the results back. I also suggest you to use browser dev tools and report what actual DOM is (what elements browser creates)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>CMS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function show_content(){
          let lines = window.document.getElementsByClassName('file-line');
          for (let i of lines) {
            i.style.display = 'block';
          }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?php
          $fh = fopen("home.txt", "r");
          while (!feof($fh)) {
            $line = fgets($fh);
            echo '<div class="file-line" style="display:none;">'.$line.'</div>';
          }
          fclose($fh);
       ?>

       <a href="#" onclick="show_content()">Show it!</a>

     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Fame Famous I'm gonna remove the id in the div your echoing out, cause you shouldn't have more then one element with that id, use classes instead

Comment: @Fame Famous if that doesn't work then I would guess that your file is not in the correct place (file path is incorrect). You can var_dump($line); or var_dump($fh) to make sure your actually reading from the file.

Comment: Here is my code that did not display the data inside the text file that i actually want. just listen i want when i click on an html the text file on the same page must open

Comment: here is my code $myFile = "file.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
    $theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
    fclose($fh);
    echo '<div id="hidden_content" style="display:none">'.$theData.'</div>';
HTML Link:

<a href="#" onclick="show_content()">Show it!</a>
Javascript:

function show_content(){
    document.getElementByID('hidden_content').style.display = 'block';
}

Comment: please find any if there is why it is not showing the content inside the text file

Comment: First edit the code in your question to show all the relevant html. Your html doesn't have a body.

Comment: @FameFamous display='active' was issue I believe

Comment: And don't need href pointing to anything if your just showing the div's, I updated the answer

Comment: @FameFamous you edited my answer, you were suppose to edit your question. But no worries, try the code as it is now, in my answer. Does it work?

Comment: the code is still not working. i am running the code that i have update your code it is not working now i must have to do

Comment: @FameFamous ok, I figured it out, updating answer now

Comment: @FameFamous you good now? Did it work? I tested code, should work now. Only issue could be if it's not loading file now.

Comment: thank you very much you code is running. I really appreciate your work .

Comment: why the files are not overridding @cmac, when i click on the link one the first file must be shown and when i click second file must be shown why they concatenates when i click on the second link

Comment: Not sure what your saying? You asking why it's concatenating instead of writing over the file?